# Dynamic user rating table in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to realize the effect of changing positions, for example, if a person's points increases, it goes from third place to first, the one who was in the first place, moved to the second and so on. The table is:
[image]

I found only one plugin for this and it's dated by 2011.
http://blog.scottlogic.com/archive/2010/12/rankingTableUpdate.js
How this is usually code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer here http://www.hitthebits.com/2012/05/animating-list-with-css3-transitions.html
The main idea is to set position: absolute to list items. After that I'm updated rank and in cycle set offsets to them, top and left/right position. 
To make a change of position visible, I'm using transition-duration property.
The example in fiddle:

```js
var players2;
var timerId2;
var updateInterval2 = 1000;
function descending2(a, b) { return a.score < b.score ? 1 : -1; }

function reposition2() {
    var height = 50;
    var y = height;
    for(var i = 0; i < players2.length; i++) {
            players2[i].$item.css({
                top: y + "px",
                position: "absolute"
            });
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            players2[i].$item.css({
                right: "150px",
                left: 0
            });
            players2[i].$item.find(".bg").css({
                left: "-1px",
                right: "",
                background: "url(http://s019.radikal.ru/i602/1508/06/6f165f2bc82e.png) no-repeat 0 0",
                width: "151px"
            });
        } else {
            y += height;
            players2[i].$item.css({
                right: 0,
                left: "150px"
            });
            players2[i].$item.find(".bg").css({
                left: "",
                right: 0,
                background: "url(http://s017.radikal.ru/i439/1508/df/41c86390f1b4.png) repeat 0 0",
                width: "149px"
            });
        }
    }
}

function updateBoard2() {
    var player = getRandomPlayer2();
    player.score += getRandomScoreIncrease2();
    player.$item.find(".score").text(player.score);

    players2.sort(descending2);
    updateRanks2(players2);
    reposition2();
}

function getRandomPlayer2() {
    var index = getRandomBetween2(0, players2.length);
    return players2[index];
}

function getRandomScoreIncrease2() {
    return getRandomBetween2(500, 1000);
}

function getRandomBetween2(minimum, maximum) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * maximum) + minimum;
}

function updateRanks2(players2) {
    for(var i = 0; i < players2.length; i++) {
        players2[i].$item.css("position","absolute").find(".rank").text(i + 1);
        switch(i) {
            case (i % 2 == 0):
                players2[i].$item.css("right","0");
                break;
            case (i % 2 == 1):
                players2[i].$item.css("left","0");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
function resetBoard2() {
    var $list = $(".leaders .leaders-table");
    if (timerId2 !== undefined) {
        clearInterval(timerId2);
    }

    players2 = [
        {name: "raiseonce", score: 35354},
        {name: "skv_055", score: 35300},
        {name: "senna1993", score: 25000},
        {name: "sakis68", score: 24600},
        {name: "nemosea18", score: 1000},
        {name: "You", score: 0}
    ];
    var listHeight = (50 * Math.ceil(1/2*players2.length)) + 10;
    $list.css("height",listHeight + "px");
    for (var i = 0; i < players2.length; i++) {
        if (players2[i].name == "You") {
                var $item = $("<li class='current-user clearfix'><div class=bg></div>" +
                "<div class=name><span class=rank>" + (i + 1) + "</span>" + ". " + players2[i].name + "</div>" +
                "<div class=score>" + players2[i].score + "</div>" +
                "</li>");
        } else {
                var $item = $("<li class=clearfix><div class=bg></div>" +
                "<div class=name><span class=rank>" + (i + 1) + "</span>"+ ". " + players2[i].name + "</div>" +
                "<div class=score>" + players2[i].score + "</div>" +
                "</li>");
        }
        players2[i].$item = $item;
        $list.append($item);
    }

    timerId2 = setInterval('updateBoard2();', updateInterval2);

    reposition2();
}

resetBoard2();
```

```css
.leaders {
  position: relative; 
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.leaders-table {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300px; }
  .leaders-table li {
     background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #afafaf;
    width: 149px;
    height: 42px;
    line-height: 42px;
    font-size: 11px; }
    .leaders-table li:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0; }
    .leaders-table li:nth-child(odd) {
      float: left; }
    .leaders-table li:nth-child(even) {
      float: right; }
    .leaders-table li .bg {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      height: 42px; }
    .leaders-table li .name {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      float: left;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding-left: 22px;
      width: 87px;
      color: black; }
    .leaders-table li .score {
      margin-left: 10px;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
      float: right;
      width: 49px;
      font-weight: 600;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: white; }
    .leaders-table li.current-user .name {
      color: #ff5300; }
    .leaders-table li.current-user .score {
      color: #ff5300; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leaders">
                <ul class="leaders-table">
                     </ul>
               </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Andrew93/z770vsgz/2/